# Population Pyramid with Gender surplus in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, plotly, population

On Wikipedia, there is a fantastic population pyramid that shows gender surplus.
How could I recreate this in R using ggplot2, &/or plotly?

It's essentially a dual-stacked bar plot, which has been oriented by 90 degrees.

```
# Here is some population data

library(wpp2019)
# Male
data(popM)
# Female
data(popF)
```

[image: Population Pyramid with Gender surplus]

[Wikipedia: Demographics of the United States](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demographics_of_the_United_States)

Comment: What have you tried already?

Comment: Only wrangling the data, I have no idea where to start to create the plot orientations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the code below most of the work is in the data shaping, while the ggplot code is relatively straightforward.

```r
library(wpp2019)
library(tidyverse)
data(popM)
data(popF)

list(Male=popM, Female=popF) %>% 
  imap(~.x %>% 
         filter(name=="World") %>% 
         select(age, !!.y:=`2020`)) %>% 
  reduce(full_join) %>% 
  mutate(age = factor(age, levels=unique(age)),
         `Female surplus` = pmax(Female - Male, 0),
         `Male surplus` = pmax(Male - Female, 0),
         Male = Male - `Male surplus`,
         Female = Female - `Female surplus`) %>% 
  pivot_longer(-age) %>%
  mutate(value = case_when(grepl("Male", name) ~ -value, 
                           TRUE ~ value),
         name = factor(name, levels=c("Female surplus", "Female", 
                                      "Male surplus", "Male"))) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(value, age, fill=name)) +
    geom_col() + 
    geom_vline(xintercept=0, colour="white") + 
    scale_x_continuous(label=function(x) ifelse(x < 0, -x, x),
                       breaks=scales::pretty_breaks(6)) +
    labs(x=NULL, y=NULL, fill=NULL) +
    scale_fill_discrete(type=RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(name="RdBu", n=4)[c(1,2,4,3)],
                        breaks=c("Male surplus", "Male", "Female","Female surplus")) +
    theme_bw() +
    theme(legend.position="bottom")
```

[image]

As another option, you can place the vertical axis labels between the bars. This version also uses faceting, so we can easily label the facets by gender. Then in the legend we only need to label the surplus portions of the bars.

```r
library(ggpol)
library(ggthemes)

list(Male=popM, Female=popF) %>% 
  imap(~.x %>% 
         filter(name=="World") %>% 
         select(age, !!.y:=`2020`)) %>% 
  reduce(full_join) %>% 
  mutate(age = factor(age, levels=unique(age)),
         `Female surplus` = pmax(Female - Male, 0),
         `Male surplus` = pmax(Male - Female, 0),
         Male = Male - `Male surplus`,
         Female = Female - `Female surplus`) %>% 
  pivot_longer(-age) %>%
  mutate(facet = factor(ifelse(grepl("Female", name), "Female", "Male"),
                        c("Male","Female")),
         value = case_when(grepl("Male", name) ~ -value, 
                           TRUE ~ value),
         name = factor(name, levels=c("Female surplus", "Female", 
                                      "Male surplus", "Male"))) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(value, age, fill=name)) +
    geom_col() + 
    geom_vline(xintercept=0, colour="white") + 
    scale_x_continuous(label=function(x) ifelse(x < 0, -x, x),
                       breaks=scales::pretty_breaks(3),
                       expand=c(0,0)) +
    labs(x=NULL, y=NULL, fill=NULL) +
    facet_share(vars(facet), scales="free_x") +
    scale_fill_discrete(type=RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(name="RdBu", n=4)[c(1,2,4,3)],
                        breaks=c("Male surplus", "Female surplus")) +
    theme_clean() +
    theme(legend.position="bottom",
          legend.background=element_blank(),
          legend.key.height=unit(4,"mm"),
          legend.margin=margin(t=0), 
          plot.background=element_blank(),
          strip.text=element_text(face="bold", size=rel(0.9)))
```

[image]

Comment: The 2nd code behaves very weirdly on the country "Oman". I also tried it on some other data and it did weird things at times. The 1st code is very stable.

Answer (score 2):

It's not the tidyiest of approaches, but this should work:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(wpp2019)
#> Warning: package 'wpp2019' was built under R version 4.1.1

data(popM)
data(popF)

# Assuming structure of popM and popF is parallel
df <- data.frame(
  age = factor(popM$age, unique(popM$age)),
  male = popM$`2020`,
  female = popF$`2020`
)[popM$name == "World",]

ggplot(df, aes(y = age)) +
  geom_col(aes(x = female, fill = "female surplus"), width = 1) +
  geom_col(aes(x = -male,  fill = "male surplus"), width = 1) +
  geom_col(aes(x =  pmin(male, female), fill = "female"), width = 1) +
  geom_col(aes(x = -pmin(male, female), fill = "male"), width = 1)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-09-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>